# Which fonts are supported in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: fonts, wolfram-cloud

I recently suggested creating dynamic community ads with Wolfram Cloud.  [@C.E. made a proof of concept ad to show that it works well.](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1822/12)

Fonts are an important part of graphics design.  It is useful to know which ones we can use for generating graphics using the cloud service.

**Question: Which fonts can be used in Wolfram Cloud?**

---

To clarify, when using the web interface, `Style["FooBar", FontFamily -> someFont]` works with any font that is installed locally on my computer and that my browser has access to.  But `Rasterize@Style[..., FontFamily -> ...]` only works with fonts which are installed in the cloud.  Which are these?

Alternatively, from Mathematica, which fonts work with `CloudEvaluate[Rasterize@Style[..., FontFamily -> ...]]`?

Answer (score 7):

A partial and likely incomplete answer to this is the following:

```
fonts = FileNameTake /@ 
   FileNames@
    FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Fonts", 
      "TrueType", "*"}];

names = Union@Flatten[
  StringCases[#, StartOfString ~~ Shortest[name__] ~~ "-" :> name] & /@
    fonts
  ]
```

In the cloud this yields the following list:

```
{AlegreyaSC, ClearSans, Cousine, DroidSerif, 
 EBGaramond08, EBGaramond12, EBGaramondSC08, EBGaramondSC12,
 Economica, Felipa, Inconsolata, Kalam, 
 Lato, LeagueGothic, Mathematica, MathematicaMono, MathematicaSans,
 Oswald, PlayfairDisplay, Roboto, RobotoCondensed, RobotoSlab, 
 ShadowsIntoLightTwo, SourceCodePro, SourceSansPro, SourceSerifPro, 
 TitilliumWeb, VeraMono, YanoneKaffeesatz}
```

We can test these like so:

```
CloudEvaluate[Rasterize@Style["Font name: " <> #, FontFamily -> #]] & /@ names
```

This test reveals that Mathematica, MathematicaMono, and MathematicaSans cannot be used with general text.  The rest seem to work.

Additionally, we can try these:

```
$FontFamilies

{Arial,Courier,Gill Sans,Helvetica,Source Sans Pro,Times New Roman,Trebuchet MS}
```

Of these, at least Arial, Helvetica and Trebuchet MS are not available.  They fall back to the default font which looks different from any of these.

---

This is a naive function to try to test whether a certain font name is available (or rather: whether it renders differently from the default).

```
CloudEvaluate@Module[{rast},
   rast = 
    Rasterize[
      Style["Abcd Efgh Ijkl Opqr Stuv Wzyx ", FontFamily -> #, 
       FontSize -> 20], "Image"] &;
   # -> (ImageData[rast["not a font"]] != ImageData[rast[#]])
   ] &
```