# Can Mathematica convert bitmaps to vectors?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, polygons, svg-format

I know that in *Mathematica*  doesn't seem to support vector graphics for 3D ploting, e.g. [exporting-2d-projection-of-3d-graph-in-svg-form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159447/exporting-2d-projection-of-3d-graph-in-svg-form). But as far as I know, some paid software can achieve this.  For example, [vectormagic](https://vectormagic.com/).

What is the principle behind this, and Can *Mathematica* emulate their algorithms to achieve this? One feasible approach seems to be path-tracing.

```
  Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], FaceForm[Blue], 
           PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicuboctahedron", "Faces"]}], 
         Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

For example, I want to convert the polyhedron above into a vector graphic. Taking a step back, are there any free software options to achieve this?

**Edit:**  Thanks to *Stephen Luttrell*  for reminding me of the function `ImageGraphics`.

[image]

Although I gave it a try, there are some minor details that are not quite satisfactory, such as jagged edges. Maybe I missed some options.

Comment: `$ExportFormat` shows `SVG`

Comment: @eldo Thanks. I know this; but when we import it in SVG-format, the image still appears blurry when enlarged, indicating it's not a true vector graphic.

Comment: This is a response to your title "Can Mathematica convert bitmaps to vectors?". Maybe `ImageGraphics[<image>]` will do what you want.

Comment: Well. While there are some minor details that are not entirely satisfactory (see the changes later), overall it's okay.

Comment: While this is specifically for text, it does convert well into SVG: [Converting an Unicode's image into polygon data for an SVG](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289557/89848). I also had to ask someone because I had the same problem getting a nice, real SVG.